# Track the Width of the Element when using jQuery Animate

Tags: jquery

If I animate the width of an HTML element with jQuery Animate "animate()", how can I keep track of the width that is being increased dynamically. For example I have an HTML element '' with CSS set to 'div {width: 10%;}'

```
<div></div> <!--css width set to 10%-->
```

I am incresing the width of the '' with jquery

```
$('div').animate({width: '90%'});
```

While this code executes and at the same time when the width of the element crosses '60%' I have to do something else like using 'if statement'.

In such a case how do I keep track of width while the Elements Width is being animated. I tried using ':animated' but did not work

I hope I am clear on what I want.

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/vineetgnair/0de46n7x/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0de46n7x/10/)***

```
$('button').click(function() {

    var at60triggered = false;

    $('div').animate({width: '90%'},{
        duration : 3000,
        step : function( widthPerc ) {
            if(at60triggered === false  &&  widthPerc >= 60) {
                at60triggered = true;
                // Do anything here
            }
            $('p').text( widthPerc ); // Keep track of percentage value
        }
    });

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step